# Selecting text and clicking on search button in VS Code no longer pastes selected text in the search field

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the past you were able to select text in a file, then click on folder structure search, and whatever you had selected would automatically paste in the search field. Is this functionality gone or is there any setting I can set up to get this back?

[image: folder structure search field]

Answer (score 1):

Found it in Settings -> Features -> Search -> Seed On Focus